# Run groovy shell in Android Studio Gradle project

Tags: android, groovy, android-studio

When I try to start the Groovy shell in an Android Studio gradle project I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:115)
```

I'm running Android Studio 0.3.7 on a MacBook Pro.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I've filed bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63356 for this but I'll not post this as an answer in case someone has some crazy workaround for this. In general if you see something that's a bug, and invoking a menu command and getting a stack trace certainly qualifies, please file at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug and provide detailed steps to reproduce. If you can search before filing to see if it's a duplicate, that would help a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add groovy in your `buildscript` classpath dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6'
    }
}
```

That fixed the error for me.